# how to "escape" a comma in a comma-separated list in a POST request?

Tags: javascript, string, rest, post

EDIT : the API developer provided a solution by using another delimiter and specifying it in the request (see below my answer to my own question)

---

I am sending POST requests to a RESTful API, which require a comma-separated list of arguments :

```js
var request = require('request-promise'); //promisified npm request

// the list of names is huge
// those names are stored in a MongoDB database
// the namesList is generated programmatically before the request
var namesList = "name1,name2,name3,name4"

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://myAPI/someEndPoint/',
  body: {
    key: myAccessKey,
    names: namesList
  },
  json: true
};

request(requestOptions)
.then( () => {_do_something_} );
```

It works fine for most of the names, but some of them contain a comma :

```js
var arrayNames = ["foo bar", "barfoo", "stupid, comma", "dammit"];

// is converted by my code in :

var namesList = "foo bar,barfoo,stupid, comma, dammit";
```

This inevitably leads to a wrong list being sent to the API... So, is there a way to "escape" the faulty comma programmatically when I generate the list from the array ?

Comment: So check the documentation of that service about how to escape it. It is up to the service developer on how to serialise data.

Comment: @zerkms : You wouldn't believe how minimalist their documentation is, and how long it takes to get a proper response for my question... It's not a clean GitHub repo, far from that. Besides, I asked here because I thought that might be a code mistake on my side ;-)

Comment: Well, it's **ONLY** the developer of the API that can tell you how they expect you to escape it. It is them who developed this odd way of serialising an array of strings, and we have no idea what they had in mind when they designed it and how they assume you to transfer strings with comma inside.

Comment: @zerkms : oh well... you're killing me, but yeah, makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long awaited answer from the API developer has arrived (sent an e-mail a while ago), and the solution is as simple as it is efficient : just use another delimiter :

```js
var namesList = "name1;name2;name3;name4" // use ';' instead of ',' here...

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://myAPI/someEndPoint/',
  body: {
    key: myAccessKey,
    names: namesList,
    delimiter: ';' // and specify the delimiter there !
  },
  json: true
};

request(requestOptions)
.then( () => {_do_something_} );
```

I don't know if the `delimiter` field is standard or specific to this API, but it works perfectly for my use case !

Comment: You need to add extra logic to find if there is `;` somewhere in your data then :-) And if it's both `;` and `,` in your strings - you need to fallback to something else. That's what happens when someone invents their own serialisation algorithm. Don't do that at home :-)

Comment: @zerkms : completely right ;-) ! Luckily, all the different names in that case are known and there are no ` ; `... But with the freedom to choose my delimiter, I have added safety nets and a warning in my logs => will fall back to a scarce delimiter if need be ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can this really be called a solution? The fundamental problem of dealing with characters that match the delimiter is still there.

Comment: Is it possible to implement the same in jquery ??

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate thru your list that you are sending, enclose comma inside a string with double quotes. 
Then handle those double quotes on the server side.
This will preserve your list integrity

use something like this to replace subString:

```
str = str.replace(/,/g, '","');
```

On the serverSide, you can then ignore all commas wrapped inside double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

try

`var namesList = arrayNames.map(function(val) { return val.replace(',', '\\,');}).toString();`

Comment: There is no such generic thing as "escaping a comma", but in this case it's a home-made serialisation. Which means that it's only the person who invented the serialisation can tell if it's even possible to "escape" it.

Comment: Thx for the idea but unfortunately it doesn't work when I add one or two or three or 69 slashes before the comma xD

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!